# Advanced AJAX Page Loader ignores other JS code

Tags: plugins, javascript

I’m currently working on a WordPress site for a start-up music-studio.

On the site the user has the possibility to listen to some of the artists tracks in a built in music player.
This player will continue to play the music track as the user is navigation through the site.
In order to make this work the site is using a plugin called “Advanced AJAX Page Loader”.

But there is one major problem with this plugin; It ignores all other inline JavaScript on the site.
I’ve tried to Google it and read the FAQ on the plugins’ WordPress site. All say the same thing:

> Put the binding code in the JS file after the line which says "DROP
>   YOUR RELOAD CODES BELOW HERE"

But there is one problem with this.. What JS file? I have 3 JS files in plugin folder and none of them are containing the sentence "DROP YOUR RELOAD CODES BELOW HERE”.

Another thing I recently discovered was that on the plugin page in WordPress it constantly says that an update is required for this plugin (v. 9.1).
But when I try to update it, it then says that the download failed because the URL is invalid. But when I check the plugins’ WordPress site, it says that version 2.7.7 (the one that I have) is the current one??

So is there anyone who knows a fix to all this or maybe an alternate or better plugin?
Cause right now, the plugin is totally useless to me.

Thanks